# How to enable IPV6 support in IBM Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ipv6, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I need to install a IPV6 haproxy docker in IBM Cloud Kubernetes service. All info I see is just about IPV4. I don't even know if IBM Kubernetes supports IPV6 so I can support IPV6 requests in my docker instance deployed in one of my cluster nodes.
Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service does not use IPV6 for cluster services.

Comment: Well... too bad to know that but at least seems the correct answer to my question. Thanks.